# Como saber cuantas palabras tiene una cadena en mips(Mars)

Tags: ensamblador, mips32

tengo la cadena "Hola mundo" en A y quiero saber cuantas palabras forman A y que ese numero lo guarde en D como en la figura que os dejo abajo. Si me podéis echar un cable en eso se lo agradecería mucho. Gracias de antemano

A → "Hola Mundo"

D → 2

.data

A: .asciiz "Hola Mundo"

B: .space 100

C: .space 100

D: .space 100

.text

add $t0, $t0 , $zero #pares

addi $t1,$t1,1 #impares
la $s0, A  #cargas todo la cadena
la $s1, B
la $s2, C
la $s3, D
bucleParImpar:
add $t2, $t0,$s0
lb $t3, 0($t2)
sb $t3, 0($s1)
beq $t3,0, exit
addi $s1,$s1,1
addi $t0,$t0,2
add $t2, $t1,$s0
lb $t3, 0($t2)
beq $t3,0, exit
addi $s2,$s2,1
addi $t1,$t1 ,2
sb $t3, 0($s2)
j bucleParImpar
exit:
li $v0 10
syscall

Comment: Te recomiendo que compartas el código/investigación que llevas cómo avance, de lo contrario podría parecer que lo que quieres es que te resuelvan tu tarea, lo cual no es bien visto en el sitio. Te recomiendo leer el último punto de [este link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) de la comunidad.

Comment: @FranAcuna `.data
A: .asciiz "Hola Mundo"
B: .space 100
C: .space 100
D: .space 100
.text
add $t0, $t0 , $zero #pares
addi $t1,$t1,1 #impares


la $s0, A  #cargas todo la cadena 
la $s1, B 
la $s2, C 
la $s3, D 

bucleParImpar:
 add $t2, $t0,$s0
 lb $t3, 0($t2)
 sb $t3, 0($s1)
 beq $t3,0, exit
 addi $s1,$s1,1
 addi $t0,$t0,2
 
 add $t2, $t1,$s0
 lb $t3, 0($t2)
 beq $t3,0, exit
 addi $s2,$s2,1
 addi $t1,$t1 ,2
 sb $t3, 0($s2)
 j bucleParImpar 
exit:
 li $v0 10
 syscall`

Comment: Excelente Berni! Te recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que obtengas tu primera medalla. Solo una cosa, no agregues el código en la sección de comentarios es sumamente dificil de leer. Por favor, utiliza el botón `editar` y agrégalo a tu pregunta.

Comment: @FranAcuna gracias y listo :)